# Twitter-style Tagging with Hashtags ? Devs? Anyone?

Tags: add-on-development, tags

First, HUGE props to the people who've worked so hard to create this forum.  EE desperately needs (and deserves) a community like this.

Wondering if any of you have experience with Twitter-style hashtagging in EE?  I found an old 1.x extension called [Twagger](https://github.com/AboutWout/twagger.ee_addon) that does it. But it has not been ported to EE 2.

I really want to streamline the tagging process in SafeCracker.

If I can't find a 2.x extension that will do this, I'd be interested in contracting someone to do it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) Just a heads up that if nothing exists already, this isn't a good place to find a developer to build it for you (try Twitter, EE jobs forum, and possibly Reddit or LinkedIn, in that order).

Comment: Thank you for that, Adrian.  Honestly, I don't mean to be dense, but when it comes to EE, it seems I'm ALWAYS a freaking idiot...  Why is this a poor place to find devs?  Especially now that Ellis killed the jobs forum?  And I wouldn't have the first idea about how to find an able/willing EE guru on Twitter.

Comment: I need to make a correction to my original post.  Twagger does not perform the way I thought it did.  It's close-ish to what I'm looking for, but a direct 1.X to 2.X conversion won't work.

Comment: JJ - Adrian's comment is regarding the rules of the StackExchange network overall, which this ExpressionEngine Answers site is a part of. It is a Q&A site - asking specific questions which are answerable on-site. It's not for general discussion. [See the FAQ.](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Did you find the solution already? If not, I'd be willing to develop something like that. My email is in profile.

Answer (score 1):

While being not really tagging solution, [Crosslinking](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/crosslinking) might be of some help to you.

(As mentioned above, you need to be more specific to get good answers to your questions)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if I fully understand what you want. Are you looking for a 'tagging' solution, where people can enter tags from the front end (regardless of hash, but provides a filter for posts) or are you looking for something that converts #keywords to links, if someone used one anywhere in a post?

If you want tags to be filters, look at [Solspace's Tag](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tag/) or [DevDemon's Tagger](http://www.devdemon.com/tagger/). Either will provide a good system for dealing with tags.

If you want a system that replaces #keywords, with links. Then you'll want to use a Find and Replace plugin against the body or main text field. Something like '[Low Replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace)' should work. You'd still want either Tag or Tagger to do the processing.

So you would do something like:

```
<!-- Note: Find words with a hashtag (#) and encase with a url to the tag processing page -->
{exp:low_replace find="#\w+" replace="<a href=\"/tags/tag/#\w+\">#\w+</a>" regex="yes"}
  {post_body}
{/exp:low_replace}
```

My regex use is **atrocious**. So don't expect that to work as is. I work with another programmer, who just smirks, when he sees my regex, which I kindly place a note on, and he fixes. So maybe a kind soul here will do that as well.

But the find and replace will swap out any #keyword within the body and make it a link. The link would then point to a page being handled by Tag or Tagger or even search. In fact, if the items should be found from any body field, you may wish to use the search function.

I find the tag functions of Tag and Tagger work best in a single, pre-defined field or using their built in tagging method. No hashtags needed. The user just adds keywords/tags at the end of a post.

Yuri's [CrossLinking](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/crosslinking) might allow you to get rid of the regex find and replace. So you may want to look at that as well.